Having an issue when fetching from JS to PHP
it goes to the fetch part and instantly throws back the error
index.php file:
<?php
session_start();

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$apiKey = 'API_KEY';
$model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo';
$endpoint = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';

$userMessage = trim($_POST['message']); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['chat_history'])) {
    $_SESSION['chat_history'] = [];
}

if (!empty($userMessage)) {
    $_SESSION['chat_history'][] = ['role' => 'user', 'content' => $userMessage];
}

$_SESSION['chat_history'] = array_filter($_SESSION['chat_history'], function($message) {
    return !empty($message['content']);
});

$client = new Client();

try {
    $response = $client->post($endpoint, [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $apiKey,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'json' => [
            'model' => $model,
            'messages' => $_SESSION['chat_history'],
            'max_tokens' => 50,
        ],
    ]);

    $body = $response->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($body, true);

    if (isset($data['choices'][0]['message']['content'])) {
        $botMessage = $data['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
        $_SESSION['chat_history'][] = ['role' => 'assistant', 'content' => $botMessage];
        echo json_encode(['message' => $botMessage]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'No response from ChatGPT']);
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>


script.js file:
document.getElementById('chatForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userMessage = document.getElementById('userMessage').value;
    const chatHistory = document.getElementById('chatHistory');


    chatHistory.innerHTML += `<p><strong>User: </strong> ${userMessage}</p>`;
    document.getElementById('userMessage').value = '';

    
    fetch('index.php', {  // fetching
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: 'message=' + encodeURIComponent(userMessage)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.message) {
                chatHistory.innerHTML += `<p><strong>Bot:</strong> ${data.message}</p>`;
                console.log("Gone!")
            } else {
                chatHistory.innerHTML += `<p><strong>Error:</strong> ${data.error}</p>`;
            }
            chatHistory.scrollTop = chatHistory.scrollHeight;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            chatHistory.innerHTML += `<p>Error: ${error.message}</p>`;
            chatHistory.scrollTop = chatHistory.scrollHeight;
        });
});


So, when i send a message from html, i am getting this error:
Error: Unexpected token '<', "
i tried to log "Hello" to the console to get where i'm getting error but it is not working after fetch
I tried to remove <> tags from JS file but it didn't work

Have you checked what the actual returned content is from the fetch URL? You can use the Network developer tool in your browser.

Yes, I checked the actual response and its status is 200 but content type is application/x-httpd-php

That error "unexpected token" is because javascript is trying to parse JSON out of the response, but the response is not valid JSON because, presumably Apache is throwing an error, which it does in HTML by default. The "unexpected <" is an HTML tag that is trying to display an error. Look at the BODY of the response, not the HTTP code or content type.

bro can u give me some instructions how to log response body into console?

Replace .then(response => response.json()).then... with .then(response => response.text()).then(data => console.log(data))

But you don't need to change your code. Just look at the Response in the Network tab of DevTools.
